# Cannot use bson.NewObjectId() to bson.ObjectId type in GO

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

For the record, I'm learning Go. I'm trying to set value for model that hold `bson.objectId` type using `bson.newObjectId()` but I got following error :

`cannot use bson.NewObjectId() (value of type bson.ObjectId) as bson.ObjectId value in struct literal`

Is there any solution for this, or am I doing it wrong ? thank you.

Comment: can you please include your code where you are making this change? It is hard to get the context with this limited information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was just importing different bson package from my main source code (github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson) with my shared module that I am currently working on (gopkg.in/mgo.v2). Thank you for your response @ShubhamChadokar :)